# Silverstripe better form looking on templates

Tags: css, forms, styles, customization, silverstripe

I have a designed template on photoshop from a client. My interrogation... When I saw the template is: Can I put 2 fields side-by-side? I want to have f_firstname and f_lastname on one row... Is there anyway to inject tags or piece of code with classes like ex: **div="column1of2"** $field_here **close div** to have a 2 columns for 2 fields?

Actually, code generate each fields are on separates rows. That's not very pretty. Possible?

I have this code :

```
private static $allowed_actions = array(
    'FormInfolettre'
);

public function FormInfolettre() {
    $fields = new FieldList(
        EmailField::create('f_email', 'Votre courriel'),
        TextField::create('f_firstname', 'Votre prénom'),
        TextField::create('f_lastname', 'Votre nom'),
        TextField::create('f_message', 'Votremessage'),
);

    $actions = new FieldList(
        FormAction::create("Soumettre")->setTitle("Soumettre")
    );

    $required = new RequiredFields(
        array(
            'f_email',
            'f_firstname',
            'f_lastname',
            'f_message',

        ));

    $form = new Form($this, 'FormInfolettre', $fields, $actions, $required);

    return $form;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create [FieldGroups](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.3/class-FieldGroup.html) for the container div and [add extra css classes to the fields](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.3/class-FormField.html#_addExtraClass) like

```
$fields = FieldList::create();

$firstName = TextField::create('FirstName','First Name')->addExtraClass('small-8 medium-4 large-5 columns');
$surname = TextField::create('Surname','Surname')->addExtraClass('small-12 medium-5 large-5 columns');

$nameGroup = FieldGroup::create($firstName, $surname);

$fields->push($nameGroup);
```

Comment: @NewbieSSProgrammer thanks for fixing a bug in my answer ;)

Comment: No problem! You help me I'll help you ;)

Answer (score 2):

I believe this can be done in the new versions by adding your fields to groups then adding a class and CSS for those classes, one group that is left aligned and the other right aligned.

Alternatively, I forked an older version of Userforms a while back to accomplish this.
https://github.com/helenclarko/silverstripe-userforms

Answer (score 1):

I've always liked using a SilverStripe template for the forms. To do this, we need to use the **forTemplate** function to define the template. With the code below, we are setting the template name to **MyForm**

```
<?php

class MyForm extends Form {
    function __construct($controller, $name) {
        ...
    }

    function forTemplate() {
        return $this->renderWith(array(
            $this->class
        ));
    }
}
```

We create a **MyForm.ss** template in **themename/templates/Includes**

A form layout would be something like:

```
<form $FormAttributes>

<% loop $Fields %>
  <% if $Message %><p style="color:red; padding: 0 0 3px 0; margin:0">$Message</p><% end_if %>
<% end_loop %>

<% if $Message %>
  <p id="{$FormName}_error" class="message $MessageType">$Message</p>
<% else %>
  <p id="{$FormName}_error" class="message $MessageType" style="display: none"></p>
<% end_if %>

$Fields.FieldByName(SecurityID)

<div class="row">
  <div class="large-6 medium-6 small-12 columns">
    $Fields.FieldByName(FirstName)
    <small class="error">Please enter your first name</small>
  </div>

  <div class="large-6 medium-6 small-12 columns">
    $Fields.FieldByName(Surname)
    <small class="error">Please enter your surname</small>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="typographyr">
  <button class="button">Submit</button>
</div>

</form>
```

Comment: Hi @Gavin Bruce, It's seem complicated for a beginer like me. I understand the MyForm.ss as template but, what is the codes is in the three dot under function __construct? I'm curious your code. ;)

Comment: The 3 dots is just for missing code. Its where you would create your fields to be in the form and any other bits you need.

Comment: Yes I know that. I've asking you if you have an example of form function to put under *function __construct*.

Comment: No need to subclass if you just want to use another template for the form. You can set it using http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-Form.html#_setTemplate Subclassing totally makes sense if you have custom behaviour in the form.